# Перебор объекта

Tags: javascript

Есть матрица которая представлена объектом объектов.
Например такая:

```
let matrix = {
    1: {0: 0, 1: Infinity, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 11},
    2: {0: 4, 1: 10, 2: Infinity, 3: 0, 4: 0},
    3: {0: 0, 1: 4, 2: 1, 3: Infinity, 4: 6},
    4: {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 7, 3: 2, 4: Infinity},
    5: {0: Infinity, 1: 0, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 8},
}
```

Как можно перебрать значения в матрице по колонке?

Comment: Нафига для матрицы вместо массивов использовать объекты? Впрочем, код перебора от этого почти не поменяется, просто вместо нормального цикла придётся сделать перебор ключей объекта.

Comment: Object.values(matrix).forEach ()

Comment: @Qwertiy приходится использовать объекты потому что мне важно запоминать и индексы потому что в один момент программа может убрать строку 1 и колонку 4 например, но порядковые номера остальных строк и колонок должны остаться неизменны, то есть строки были 1 2 3 4 5 а станут 2 3 4 5,по этому использовать массивы и перебирать объект  так как если бы это был массив не получиться.

Comment: Массивы тоже можно делать дырявыми.

Answer (score 0):

Для обхода можно воспользоваться циклом [`for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in):

```js
let matrix = {
    1: {0: 0, 1: Infinity, 2: 5, 3: 2, 4: 11},
    2: {0: 4, 1: 10, 2: Infinity, 3: 0, 4: 0},
    3: {0: 0, 1: 4, 2: 1, 3: Infinity, 4: 6},
    4: {0: 1, 1: 0, 2: 7, 3: 2, 4: Infinity},
    5: {0: Infinity, 1: 0, 2: 5, 3: 6, 4: 8},
}

function row(matrix, n){
  for (var i in matrix[n]){
    console.log(matrix[n][i]);
  }
}

function col(matrix, n){
  for (var i in matrix){
    console.log(matrix[i][n]);
  }
}

row(matrix, 1);
col(matrix, 0);
```